# How AliasJoin in QueryOver for this sample

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, queryover

The Person class has a association by Identity class (one-to-one) FirstName and LastName are a property of Person class also Sex and BirthDate are a property of Identity class.

I have a sql query as the following examples:

```
select FirstName,LastName,Identity.Sex,Identity.BirthDate from Person_Person as Person
inner join Person_Identity as Identity on Person.Id = Identity.Person_id_fk
WHERE FirstName like '%jack%' and LastName like '%smit%'
```

I convert it into QueyOver.

```
var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPersonDto.FirstName)) //necessary
   q = q.Where(p => p.FirstName.IsLike(searchPersonDto.FirstName, MatchMode.Anywhere));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPersonDto.LastName))  //necessary
   q = q.Where(p => p.LastName.IsLike(searchPersonDto.LastName, MatchMode.Anywhere));

Person aliasPerson = null; 
q = q.SelectList(list => list
     .Select(p => p.Id).WithAlias(() => aliasPerson.Id)
     .Select(p => p.FirstName).WithAlias(() => aliasPerson.FirstName)
     .Select(p => p.LastName).WithAlias(() => aliasPerson.LastName)
     .Select(p => p.Identity.Sex).WithAlias(() => aliasPerson.Identity.Sex)
     .Select(p => p.Identity.BirthDate).WithAlias(() => aliasPerson.Identity.BirthDate))
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Person>());

q.List<Person>();
```

But join in this query is not correct. It throw a exceotion by this message :
`could not resolve property: Identity.Sex of: Domain.Entities.Person`

How I should join Identity by Person?

Updated : Add the similar linq query

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>()
        .Where(p => p.FirstName == searchPersonDto.FirstName)
        .Select(p => new Person(p.Id)
        {            
            FirstName = p.FirstName,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            Identity = new Identity()
            {
                Sex = p.PersonIdentity.Sex,
                BirthDate = p.Identity.BirthDate
            }
        }).ToList<Person>();
```

I need to a query by **QueryOver** similar to  above query by **Linq**.

Comment: Looking at your query, you don't need any of the alias stuff at all...

Comment: @Phill I need to alias for `q.List<Person>()` instead of `q.List<object>()`

Comment: no you don't, .List() already returns you a type of IList<Person>

Comment: @Phill this query is like `SELECT * From Person_Person ` But I do not want it. I want this query : `SELECT FirstName,LastName, ... From Person_Person`

Comment: Ahh, now we are getting somewhere, you want to select specific columns including the relationship.

Comment: I'm not gonna bother helping you any further since you have a shit attitude towards someone helping you. Also you might want to actually clarify what you're asking for in your question.

Comment: @Phill I'm sorry
Why you so think thus? I said from the beginning that I need to a Select in QueryOver similar to my Sql query in question. And I said that I guess the problem is in JoinAlias.
Is not it? Again, apology!

Answer (score 2):

Update2: not pretty but here goes

```
var results = q
    .JoinAlias(p => p.Identity, () => identityAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(p => p.Id)
        .Select(p => p.FirstName)
        .Select(p => p.LastName)
        .Select(p => identityAlias.Sex)
        .Select(p => identityAlias.BirthDate)
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(values => new Person((int)values[0])
    {            
        FirstName = (string)values[1],
        LastName = (string)values[2],
        Identity = new Identity()
        {
            Sex = (string)values[3],
            BirthDate = (DateTime)values[4],
        }
    })
    .ToList<Person>();
```

Update: from your comments i would say, this is what you need.

code to fill a PersonDto

```
PersonDTO aliasDTO = null;
q = q
    .JoinAlias(p => p.Identity, () => identityAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(p => p.Id).WithAlias(() => aliasDTO.Id)
        .Select(p => p.FirstName).WithAlias(() => aliasDTO.FirstName)
        .Select(p => p.LastName).WithAlias(() => aliasDTO.LastName)
        .Select(p => identityAlias.Sex).WithAlias(() => aliasDTO.Sex)
        .Select(p => identityAlias.BirthDate).WithAlias(() => aliasDTO.BirthDate))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<PersonDTO>())
    .List<PersonDTO>();
```

Orginal Answer:

```
q.JoinAlias(p => p.Identity, () => identityAlias)

// and later

.Select(p => identityAlias.Sex)
```

Update: in the code posted the AliasToBeanTransformer is not needed at all

```
var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPersonDto.FirstName)) //necessary
   q = q.Where(p => p.FirstName.IsLike(searchPersonDto.FirstName, MatchMode.Anywhere));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPersonDto.LastName))  //necessary
   q = q.Where(p => p.LastName.IsLike(searchPersonDto.LastName, MatchMode.Anywhere));

var results = q.Fetch(p => p.Identity).Eager
    .List<Person>();
```

Comment: I added your code. Your change has a exception by this Message : `Could not find a setter for property 'Sex' in class 'Domain.Entities.Person` . This Exception thrown in this line of code : `q.Select(p => identityAlias.Sex).WithAlias(() => aliasPerson.PersonIdentity.Sex);`

Comment: The problem is still there. `p.Identity.Sex` and `p.Identity.BirthDate` have same runtime error : `could not resolve property : ...` . I want exactly something similar in the high Sql query.

Comment: +1 First query in your answer is correct But this is not useful for me. I need to a list of Person (`List<Person>`) instead of a list of PersonDTO (`List<PersonDTO>`) .

Comment: Second query in your answer has a runtime error by this message : `Could not determine member from new PersonDTO() {FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName, ...}` . Why?

Comment: i deleted the code for the personDto because you dont need it. Use the query in the updated answer

Comment: This is eager loading and isn't according to lazy loading. 
I want to select specific columns including the relationship.
Is this any way whit lazy loading and select specific columns?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want Person objects or only some properties of the Person+Identity object?

Comment: I want select specific columns of Person and Identity in the form of a list of Person that other properties in Person object and Identity object is null. My problem exactly is same.

Comment: that would break the object contract because its not known if the Peron has null properties or not initialized properties, and lazyloading and saveing changes would break. I would strongly advice you create a personDto which encapsulated only the info you need.

Comment: For reasons I just need to Person object. I resolve this problem by linq. My linq query added to question.
I need to a `Select` in QueryOver similar to `Select` in linq query.

Comment: I am not familiar with the QueryOver too. I've always used the linq. But I would like. The QueryOver to learn and now I need to how use `Select` in `QueryOver`. The QueryOver does not support Select thus?